# Does the combo of PHP5, MySQL, and a Macbook Pro constitute a LAMP stack? If not, what does?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, macos, lamp

I mostly code in Visual Studio, I like it, but lately it's making me feel a little claustrophobic. On my MacBook Pro, I've set up PHP5 and MySQL (natively). With the built-in server on the mac, does this constitute a LAMP stack?  Is Mac OSX considered a Linux Environment?  I have VMWare Fusion 3, should I set up a Linux OS virtually in order to implement a LAMP stack? Should I just use CakePHP or Zend? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What will you use the stack for?

Comment: building web applications... My experience this far is in c++/c# .NET.  I'm interested in exploring PHP to build web applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, a very common service for setting up MySQL and Apache/PHP support on a Mac is called `MAMP`. So there you go. I guess you're on MAMP.

But actually, the OS only matters if you plan on using it. I use and enjoy the CodeIgniter PHP framework which is OS agnostic, so I really only need the `-AMP` stack.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a LAMP it's MAMP but all your applications developed for this environment will be fully compatible with the LAMP stack.
The difference it's more theoretical than practical.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, OS X is a BSD based OS, not Linux.

The setup you are talking about is generally referred to as MAMP (Mac, Apache, MySQL, PHP)

That said, it's close enough for all practical purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not something is a "LAMP stack" is irrelevant. Your machine can probably run most web applications just fine.

No, OS X is not a Linux environment, but it is just fine for running a small web server.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X is not a Linux environment, but it sure is a *nix environment, so maybe is not a LAMP in the strong sense of the word, but its as powerful and useful as one.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is Apache, you have a MAMP. LAMP strictly refers to Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

**L** inux

**A** pache

**M** ySQL

**P** HP